# How to get *args variable names in a class?

Tags: python, class, global-variables, args

I have a class that zips the given values to perform calculations and it returns a dictionary with the results per variable. While `**kwargs` can be used to get the variable names easily, it seems really unconvenient if I just want to use the original variable names. Therefore, I would like to use `**kwargs` only if a variable name needs to be specified.

Desired result:

```py
>> a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
>> x = myClass(a,b,d=c) # variable names saved as a list during initialisation
>> x.result()
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 3}
```

The inputs are `pyspark` objects, so the class is expected to get assigned variables and not values directly. Also, it is expected that each input points to a unique object.

There is a possible solution using `inspect.getouterframes()` but it is very long and doesn't seem efficient at all.

Comment: There isn't a general solution to this problem - [an object may have one name, or many, or no name at all](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm#names).

Answer (score 0):

If I could understand, you want to know outside variable names that are used as arguments of function call.
In my opinion, it's not a good idea as you are coupling outside and inside scopes.

I think it would be better to define a calling protocol, like a dict and use it as argument for your function.

```
def f1(params = None): 
   keys = None 
   ret = {}
   if (params is not None) and (isinstance(params, dict)):  
        keys = params.keys()
        for k in keys:
           <<do your job>>
           ret[k] = value
   return ret
```